# WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting is not working on .appx bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am using `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting` in my Windows Phone 8.1 winrt app.

Charts are working fine on debug mode in the phone.

But when I tried to create app package and installed the same using deployment tool in my phone, in that case charts are not working.

App is not crashing but the page with chart controls is not opening.

Please find below code

```
<Charting:Chart Name="LineChart"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0">
                <Charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                        <Setter Property="Width"
                                Value="0" />
                     </Style>
                </Charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
                <Charting:Chart.Axes>
                    <Charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X"
                                           Location="Bottom"
                                           Title="{Binding x_axis}"
                                           ShowGridLines="True"
                                           Foreground="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}"
                                           x:Name="xAxis">
                        <Charting:CategoryAxis.TitleStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="datavis:Title">
                                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                                        Value="16" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                                        Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin"
                                        Value="0,10,0,0" />
                            </Style>
                        </Charting:CategoryAxis.TitleStyle>
                        <Charting:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Charting:AxisLabel">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                        Value="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Charting:AxisLabel">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}"
                                                       TextAlignment="Right"
                                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                       Width="50"
                                                       Margin="-40,-5,0,26"
                                                       RenderTransformOrigin="1,.5">
                                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="300" />
                                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Charting:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                        <Charting:CategoryAxis.GridLineStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Line">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                        Value="{StaticResource GreyBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray"
                                        Value="2" />
                            </Style>
                        </Charting:CategoryAxis.GridLineStyle>
                    </Charting:CategoryAxis>
                    <Charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y"
                                         x:Name="yAxis"
                                         Foreground="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}"
                                         Title="{Binding y_axis}"
                                         ShowGridLines="True">
                        <Charting:LinearAxis.TitleStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="datavis:Title">
                                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                                        Value="16" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                                        Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin"
                                        Value="10" />
                            </Style>
                        </Charting:LinearAxis.TitleStyle>
                        <Charting:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Charting:AxisLabel">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                        Value="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Charting:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                        <Charting:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Line">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                        Value="{StaticResource GreyBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray"
                                        Value="2" />
                            </Style>
                        </Charting:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                    </Charting:LinearAxis>
                </Charting:Chart.Axes>
                <Charting:ColumnSeries  Margin="0"
                                        IndependentValuePath="label"
                                        IsSelectionEnabled="True"
                                        DependentValuePath="refilled">
                    <Charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Charting:ColumnDataPoint">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="{StaticResource columnBrush}" />
                        </Style>
                    </Charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                </Charting:ColumnSeries>
                <Charting:LineSeries Margin="0"
                                     IndependentValuePath="label"
                                     DependentValuePath="text"
                                     IsSelectionEnabled="True">
                    <Charting:LineSeries.PolylineStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Polyline">
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness"
                                    Value="2" />
                            <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                    Value="{StaticResource BrownBrush}" />
                        </Style>
                    </Charting:LineSeries.PolylineStyle>
                    <Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                        <!--<Style TargetType="Charting:LineDataPoint">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="{StaticResource BrownBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                    Value="1" />
                        </Style>-->
                        <Style TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="Width"
                                    Value="10" />
                            <Setter Property="Height"
                                    Value="10" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Charting:LineDataPoint">
                                        <Grid Opacity="1"
                                              ToolTipService.Placement="Left"
                                              ToolTipService.ToolTip="test">
                                            <Ellipse StrokeThickness="1"
                                                     Fill="{StaticResource BrownBrush}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                </Charting:LineSeries>
            </Charting:Chart>
```

Below is the c# code

```
(LineChart.Series[1] as LineSeries).ItemsSource = listItem;
(LineChart.Series[0] as ColumnSeries).ItemsSource = listItem;
```

Comment: share you charting control xaml.

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah please find attached code

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found out what is the problem?

Comment: Yeah @Greg I found out the root cause.
The problem is with Line chart, Bar chart and column chart. Everything works fine if I use Pie chart

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use bar chart.

Comment: @Greg please find the answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to solve the issue with **WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting**.

But I found an alternative which is much more effective.

I have used WebView control in my page with navigation set to static Html file.

Now in that Html file, I have used HighCharts (http://www.highcharts.com/) for Web and some Javascript functions.

Using **WebView.ScriptNotify** and **WebView.InvokeScriptAsync** ,I sent the

graph data to a javascript function, which in turn renders the graph of my

choice.

**c# code to set static html page to Webview**

```
Uri url = webGraph.BuildLocalStreamUri("MyTag", "index.html");
StreamUriWinRTResolver myResolver = new StreamUriWinRTResolver();
webView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(url, myResolver);
```

**index.html with reference of jquery and highcharts.js**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>

$(function () {
        window.external.notify("getY");
    });

 function getYValue(arguments) {
        var json_data = JSON.parse(arguments)
        y_value = $.map(json_data, function (el) { return el });
        loadGraph();
    }

function loadGraph() {

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'main',
            },

            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'xAxis'
                },
                categories: x_value
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'yAxis'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            series: [{
                name: yAxis,
                color: '#000',
                data: y_value
            }] //series
        }); 

    }
```

**C# code to pass data to javascript function**

```
async private void webView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Value.ToLower().Equals("gety"))
        {

            string sValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstY) 
             //lstY is list of Y values in array;

            List<string> lstValue = new List<string>() { sValue };

            await webGraph.InvokeScriptAsync("getYValue", lstValue);
        }
    }
```

So problem solved !

Comment: Could you please upload some code? It would help me a lot.

Comment: Thanks mate +1 from me.